Combinatorial expression for coefficients of $(x+y)^m (x-y)^n$
Is there a simple combinatorial expression for the coefficients of $x^hy^b$ in the polynomial $(x+y)^m (x-y)^n$, for any $m,n$?
I tried using induction but I was not able to obtain reasonable formulas.

have u tried binomial theorem?

Yes but from the binomial theorem for both terms I was not able to deduce a general formula for their product

do u know about Cauchy Product? Try taking $y$ out from both brackets.

upvoted the question and answer. lovely question and answer.

@mick Thank you!

Let $I=(x+y)^m(x-y)^n.$ WLOG $m\ge n$.
We have $$I=(x+y)^n(x-y)^n(x+y)^{m-n}$$
$$I=(x^2-y^2)^n(x+y)^{m-n}$$
Using binomial theorem:
$$I=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}(x^2)^{n-i}(-y^2)^{i}\sum_{j=0}^{m-n}\binom{m-n}{j}x^{m-n-j}y^j$$
$$I=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom n i (-1)^ix^{2n-2i}(y)^{2i}\sum_{j=0}^{m-n}\binom{m-n}{j}x^{m-n-j}y^{j}$$
Due to the arithmetic property of binomials, we can extend $m-n$ to $m$, and making a double sum
Taking them together:
$$I=\sum_{0\le i,j\le m}(-1)^i\binom n i\binom{m-n}{j} x^{2n-2i}x^{m-n-j}(-y)^{2i}y^j$$
Due to $i,j$ are integers, even square of negative $1$ are positive $1$, therefore the negative sign may be omitted:
$$I=\sum_{0\le i,j\le m} (-1)^i\binom n i\binom {m-n} j x^{n+m-2i-j} y^{2i-j}$$
Given that $h+b=m+n$, by letting $x^hy^b=x^{n+m-2i-j}y^{2i=j}$
We get $2i+j=b$
Therefore, to find the coefficients of $x^hy^b$ in $I$, we only need to find the all terms with $2i+j=b$
So if the coefficient of $x^hy^b$ is $\lambda$,
$$\lambda=\sum_{2i+j=b} (-1)^i\binom{n}{i}\binom{m-n}{j}$$
Yay, we made it!!!
Please notify me if there are mistakes in my answer, thank you.

@Winther Thank you, changes has been made!

I was wondering whether there was a more compact expression simplifyig $\lambda$. Can we rewrite in a simpler way that sum?

@Winther Changes has been made
